# Declare function as non-static and implement as static inline

Tags: c, gcc, static, inline-functions

I want to write different implementations for my function, some `inline` and some not. Thus, I want to declare the function as:

```
// MyHeader.h
int myFunc(void);

#if DO_INLINE
static inline int myFunc(void) { return 42; }
#endif
```

And then also have:

```
// MySource.c
#if !DO_INLINE
#include "myHeader.h"
int myFunc(void) { return 42; }
#endif
```

I'll specify `DO_INLINE` at compile time.

MSVC has no problems with this, but GCC (4.1.1) complains that I'm declaring a static function after I've already declared it as non-static. If I remove the `static` qualifier, and `#include "MyHeader.h"` from more than one compilation unit, it will complain about multiple definitions. (As if the `inline` functions are `extern`.) I don't quite understand why the compiler has problems with this.

I think this should be pretty obvious and unambiguous:

```
int myFunc(void);
static inline int myFunc(void) { return 42; }
```

It shouldn't require the declaration to be `static`.

That said, there is a solution to my problem that I'm trying very hard to avoid:

```
#if DO_INLINE
#define MAYBE_STATIC static
#else
#define MAYBE_STATIC 
#endif

MAYBE_STATIC int myFunc(void);
```

EDIT: Here is a more realistic use case for this: http://codepad.org/OkC0Su3v

Comment: The compiler has problems with this because the C standard says this is invalid (undefined). What are you trying to achieve (and why)? What's the problem with with the last approach?

Comment: The problem with the last approach is that it adds extra layers to the header file, making it confusing. The header file will be read by users, and should be as clean as possible - just the interface. The user shouldn't care if a function is static inline or not, thus the prototype should be the same.

Comment: As for the standard.. I admit I didn't check, but it just seems silly. Usually those constraints are to avoid ambiguity and make things easier for the compiler. Here, I see neither of those problems. The prototype is just so they know if the calls are done correctly. At most it should be a warning, because you might have made a copy/paste error.

Comment: Oh, and.. what I'm trying to achieve - make it so the user doesn't know (as they don't need to know) whether the function will be inlined or not. And that is something that I decide at compile time, based on the target OS/Architecture/etc. Sometimes inline is good, sometimes bad, for the exact same function.

Comment: Can you give a complete example of the header file how it's used with MSVC? There will be some preprocessor stuff anyway (provide a function definition or not). The `MAYBE_STATIC` approach isn't that hard to read, at least it's a thing common enough to be easily recognized. Whether a function is static or not is observable (and thus could be argued to be part of the interface) by comparing addresses from different files.

Comment: As for the C standard: If identifiers disagree on linkage, the behavior is undefined. The rationale for the standard mentions two things: Pre-C89 compilers and linkers varied a lot. Don't require an implementation to catch `void foo(void) { void bar(void); bar(); } static void bar(void);`. Wrt allowing to "overwrite" the linkage in a later declaration: In general, declarations cannot be changed later, the rules for linkage are somewhat consistent with those for types: `float n; int n;` is invalid, the type cannot be overwritten.

Comment: Lastly, I can imagine platforms where static and external functions must be called differently so the compiler possibly needs to know at the point of a call.

Comment: You make some completely valid points, so I see why they disallowed it. I still wish there was a special case if the function definition was before any use, as in the example above - The definition is in the header along with the declaration. Anyway, you asked for a complete example.. I can't give you my exact code, but this is an isomorphous realistic use case: http://codepad.org/OkC0Su3v

Comment: I see, thanks. I'll experiment a little, maybe I get an idea. Regarding my last comment: Different ABIs for static and external functions are at least hard with function pointers, and thinking about it, it doesn't sound like it was the intent of the standard to allow for that.

Comment: The example looks like you always provide an external definition. Inlining is (to some degree) independent of linkage, is there anything wrong with providing the external function and optionally provide an inline definition in the header? Gcc seems to expect an external definition for `inline` (without `extern`), but not for `extern inline`; I can't find where this is mandated by the standard, though.

Comment: I think `extern inline` means something along the lines of "use this inline function if you can, and if not, compile externally and link it". I'm just not sure how it does that, because if I compile multiple files that include the definition, it never complains about multiple definitions.

Comment: I can always provide a .c file that has the same definitions for linking externally if it isn't inlined. I'm not sure how that will help me though.. I feel like it will cause a multiple definitions error. Will check later and get back.

Comment: If any declaration (in a translation unit) either doesn't contain `inline` or contains `extern inline`, and a definition is given, an external definition of the function is provided (so you'll get a multiple definitions error). If any declaration contains `inline` (with or without `extern`) a definition must be given in the same TU. (And, as always, if there is any external declaration and the function is used, a definition must exist somewhere.) I think, what you want is impossible, so you need the extra layer with the macro (but I think you want `MAYBE_INLINE` rather than `MAYBE_STATIC`).

Comment: There's an obsolescent feature (meaning it may be removed from a future standard revision) to have an `extern` re-declaration where a declaration with internal linkage is visible. `extern` is implicit for functions (wrt linkage). So e.g. `static inline int myFunc(void) { return 42; } int myFunc(void);` is valid. Not sure, if that helps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out closely enough. The implementation should be defined as "extern inline" instead:

```
// MyHeader.h
int myFunc(void);

#if DO_INLINE
extern inline int myFunc(void) { return 42; }
#endif
```

The compiler will inline this function where it sees fit, but still compile it once as a function, to make it available for linking. That part I don't need, but it doesn't really hurt.

Answer (score 2):

This header.h should work:

```
// MyHeader.h
#if DO_INLINE
static inline int myFunc(void) { return 42; }
#else
int myFunc(void);
#endif
```

Comment: Which is similar to what I wrote at the bottom with MAYBE_STATIC, except that there's duplicate code. I actually have many (dozens) of myFunc-like functions, and really don't want to repeat them.